# How can I compare numbers obtained through a command in bash in a script?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

Im trying to get the internet speed and compare it to various values and print if its good or not. All this is done in my macOS zsh terminal.

```
Var2=$(ping -c 4 www.google.com | tail -1| awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2)
  echo "Average ping time to google.com is $Var2"
  if (( $Var2 < 7 ))
  then
      echo Excellent Connection
  elif (( $Var2 < 7.5 ))
  then
      echo Good Connection
  elif (( $Var2 < 8 ))
  then
      echo Slow Connection
  elif (( $Var2 < 8.1 ))
  then
      echo Bad Connection
  fi
```

This causes a syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".609 < 7 ") four times.

Comment: Which shell do you use? Please fix your question and tags.

Comment: Mind that Bash doesn't recognize decimals.

Comment: Add a hashbang to the top of the file: `#!/usr/bin/env zsh`. A script launched from `zsh` does not use `zsh` as the interpreter without it (unlike bash).

Comment: PS: I don't think the linked duplicate question applies here; none of the answers directly address using `zsh`.